# Autolayout: Hiding a UIView without knowing Height constraint

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, autolayout

I have 2 views(say `topView` and `bottomView`) in my `UIViewController` with `topView` at top. Both views grow with `aspect ratio` constraint. `topView` and `bottomView` has 0 vertical space between them. I want to hide `bottomView` in a particular case. But problem is that I don't have `height` constraint available for it. I only have **Vertical Space constraint** between `topView` and `bottomView`. So I decided to move `bottomView` under `topView`. I tried to do following in view controller's `viewDidLayoutSubViews`

```
self.verticalSpaceConstraint.constant = -1*[bottomView intrinsicContentSize].height;
```

and

```
self.verticalSpaceConstraint.constant = -1*[bottomView bounds].size.height;
```

The `intrinsicSize` always returns (1,1) and `bounds` always returns `(0,0,320,568)`. How can I achieve this it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add height constraint (with constant value 0) and aspect ratio constraint both at a same time to the view, but these constrains should have different priorities and non of these with priority 1000 (required). Then to hide view just set programmatically priority of aspect ratio constraint lower then height constraint or vice versa to show it. Hope this helps